# Dataset of Tweets with Geolocation Data

Tags: dataset, geolocation, twitter

I'm looking for a large dataset of tweets that have geolocation data (from the U.S.).
Is there such a dataset available anywhere? I looked on infochimps, but didn't see anything.

If not, what's the best way to generate this dataset myself? Should I just run the Twitter Streaming API on my local machine (or maybe on AWS?), and then filter and save all geo-tagged tweets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Streaming API would probably be your best bet. Just use the [`location`](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/streaming_api_methods#locations) filter to set the geographic area you want to capture data from.

Here's a slightly [related question: Requesting just geotagged statuses from the Twitter API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244947/requesting-just-geotagged-statuses-from-the-twitter-api/4378413#4378413)