# Can I request/filter the twitter streaming api to return only tweets with geotags?

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I'm using the twitter4j library to access the public twitter stream. I'm trying to make a project involving geotagged tweets, and I need to collect a large number of them for testing.

Right now I am getting the unfiltered stream from twitter and only saving tweets with geotags. This is slow though because the VAST majority of tweets don't have geo tags. I want the twitter stream to send me only tweets with geotags.

I have tried using the method mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244947/requesting-just-geotagged-statuses-from-the-twitter-api), where you filter with a bounding box of size 360* by 180* but that's not working for me. I'm not getting any errors when using that filter, but I'm still getting 99% of tweets with no geotags. Here is how I'm doing it:

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
    .setOAuthConsumerKey("censored")
    .setOAuthConsumerSecret("censored")
    .setOAuthAccessToken("censored")
    .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("censored");

TwitterStream twitterStream = newTwitterStreamFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();
StatusListener listener = new MyStatusListener();
twitterStream.addListener(listener);

//add location filter for what I hope is the whole planet. Just trying to limit
//results to only things that are geotagged
FilterQuery locationFilter = new FilterQuery();
double[][] locations = {{-180.0d,-90.0d},{180.0d,90.0d}};

locationFilter.locations(locations);

twitterStream.filter(locationFilter);

twitterStream.sample();
```

Any suggestions about why I'm still getting tweets with no geotags?

Edit: I just reread the [twitter4j javadoc](http://twitter4j.org/ja/javadoc/twitter4j/TwitterStream.html#filter%28twitter4j.FilterQuery%29) on adding filters to a twitter stream, and it says "The default access level allows up to 200 track keywords, 400 follow userids and 10 1-degree location boxes." So bounding boxes may only be 1 degree wide? That's different from the original information I came across. Is that my problem? My filter request is too big so it's being ignored? I'm not getting any errors when trying to use it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

getting from filter stream then overwriting it with sample stream.

remove the last line : `twitterStream.sample();`

Comment: Wow, thanks for the answer. I almost forgot about this question. I'm still getting some tweets without geotags, but it's a big improvement. Before I would only have about 1/1000 tweets with geotags, now I'm getting about 3/5 with geotags. Not sure why I'm still missing some, but this definitely helps.